# Creating line between two points with common field?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, point

Does anyone know how I could create a line between two points that have a common code?

For example: I have the start and end point of a pipe as a lat/long for a network of pipes, each with a different ID. I want to create a line feature for each of those with the pipe ID which I can then calculate the length from.

Anyone know of any arcscript tools in ESRI software or QGIS tools I could use to accomplish this without coding?

Answer (score 3):

For ArcGIS Desktop [9.2](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=15194) or [9.3](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=15828), I have an ArcScript that draws the line and copies any attributes from the points to the line that you want to include.

In ArcGIS 10, there is the [Point to Line](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/#/Points_To_Line/00170000003s000000/) tool.

Answer (score 2):

The plugin for QGIS has been improved and is now called Points to Paths

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's a great tool to do this is located in the (free) ET Geowizards extension: Point to Polyline.

*credit for finding this goes to my coworker :)*

http://www.ian-ko.com/ET_GeoWizards/gw_NoRestrictions.htm

Answer (score 1):

I've done a similar process before but for beach profiles. As above, ETGeowizards Point to Polyline tool is what you'll need. You will need a field that distinguishes your pipe names and a field that orders the processing (i.e. that links the start and end points of the line together). I did this by adding a new field to the start/end points and then merging them together into a single point file before using the ETGeowizards tool.

Answer (score 0):

I know [Kosmo](http://www.opengis.es/) has a "Get Lines From Points" tool that does this. I'm also interested in hearing about a solution in QGIS!